# running multiple android emulators

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have more than one android emulator running, along with devices connected to the same machine.

I want to to know how to connect to a single emulator/device from the command prompt.

For example: `adb shell emulator-5554`

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `-s` switch:

`adb -s emulator-5554 shell`

Answer (score 5):

with the command

```
adb devices
```

you get a list of all connected devices like:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554  device
emulator-5556  device
emulator-5558  device
```

Then you can run all commands normally, but you have to attach the -s option
e.g.

```
adb -s emulator-5556 install helloWorld.apk
```

Take a look at the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) if you want to know more about adb.

Answer (score 0):

adb connect xx.xx.xx.xx
adb disconnect xx.xx.xx.xx

it can be X86 Emulators ;)

http://blog.gokifu.com/2011/05/android-x86-faster-emulator/